# OMP single hangs inside for

Tags: for-loop, openmp

Quick question...I have the following code:

```
void testingOMP()
{
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        #pragma omp single 
        cout << "During single: " <<omp_get_thread_num() << endl;
        cout << "After single: " << omp_get_thread_num() << endl;
    }
}
```

which hangs, giving the following output:

> During single: 1 After single: 1 After
>   single: After single: 2During single:
>   0
>
> 1

I had to ctrl+c to stop it.
The single work sharing directive assures that only one thread runs the code block having a synchronization barrier at the end. I think that's the problem because if I use master (which doesn't wait) or add nowait the program doesn't hang.

If anyone could tell me why this happens I would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Figured it out. Because one thread runs the loop more than another it wait's indefinitely.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, nesting a `single` directive directly inside a `for` directive (or vice versa) is illegal. See https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/#BindingNesting