# How to nest omp for in omp single using OpenMP

Tags: c, openmp, parallel-processing

I have a for loop, which I don't want to parallelise, which calls a function which I want to parallelise (which has a for loop in it that I want to parallelise). I want to put the parallel region outside of the whole lot, so that my threads only get created once (to reduce the overhead of thread creation).

However, at the moment I have a `omp single` covering the for loop, which calls the function and an `omp for` inside the function to deal with the internal for loop. It hands, and according to [OMP single hangs inside for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778727/omp-single-hangs-inside-for) this is because doing that is illegal!

If I can't do it that way, how can I approach it? I want to make sure that only one thread runs the outer for loop and calls the function, but that inside the function I can get full parallelism.

Is this possible? Any ideas?

Comment: Do you know that thread creation overhead is really a problem? Good OpenMP implementations might well care about that for you, keeping some threads parked internally when no parallel region is active.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what OpenMP implementation I'm using (I'm using GCC 4.3.3 if that helps) but I'm not sure whether it does this or not. I seem to get a significant slow-down (as opposed to speed-up) when I have the parallel region inside the function that gets called many times, so this suggests maybe my implementation doesn't do this.

Comment: You can check that pretty easily, by asking each thread to print its `pthread_self()` value in the beginning of the parallel region, and checking whether threads are reused or created anew.

Comment: @Alexey - Thanks for that. I've tried that, and it seems that the threads are being re-used. I'm now just slightly confused about why my code is actually running slower...but that's a different question I guess!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most implementations only create the threads once - either when the program is started or when the first parallel region is encountered.  Once created they are generally not destroyed, but put into a free thread pool (handled by the OpenMP implementation) when the end of parallel region is encountered.  This means that you should be able to put the parallel region within the loop and not have the thread creation overhead each time the parallel region is encountered.  There will be some small overhead each time the parallel region is encountered, but much smaller than when the threads are created.

Comment: That's interesting. We were warned on my parallel programming course not to keep having new parallel regions as that was very costly in overhead time. I've tried just using a `#pragma omp parallel for` inside the inner function, but the code runs significantly slower that way (with 4 threads) compared to running in serial.
Any other ideas for how I might be able to achieve this?

Comment: Generally I would agree with what you were taught.  Unfortunately, the OpenMP model has restrictions.  You could use nested parallelism to do it, but that would be worse.  If the work in the inner loop is independent of the previous iteration, then you might be able to use tasks.  Other than that, without seeing more of what you are trying to do, I am out of ideas.

Comment: @robintw, you can do certain experiments to see what causes slowdown. For example, try setting the number of threads for the parallel region to 1. This way, the overhead of OpenMP should be rather minimal, and the program should be little slower than serial. If it is much slower, then the reason is probably different than overhead from parallelism.

Answer (score 0):

What about :
 - putting your inner loop in a #pragma omp parallel
 - setting the number of active threads to one before your outer loop
 - set it back to N before calling your other function
 - put a #pragma omp for inside the function

?

Parallel sections are transient over function boundaries in OMP and setting the number of actives threads should not be too detrimental. Needs ot be tested/benchmarked though.

Comment: Changing the number of threads executing a parallel region is impossible after the region has started. From the spec: "Once the team is created, the number of threads in the team remains constant for the duration of that parallel region."

Comment: That's what I feared after sending this. Thansk for the head up Alexey

Comment: Thanks @Alexey - that's probably why this didn't work when I tried implementing it!